# Accessing list of mailbox sizes - Exchange Online / Office 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am hoping to be able, from an app written in C# or VB.NET to be able to connect to my Exchange Online Plan 1(office 365) and get a list of all users and the sizes of their mailboxes

I have spent a while reading the API and various sites about doing this, but a) not sure if possible and b) struggling to find best way to do this

Basically we have Exchange Online (Plan 1) with about 300 user mailboxes, and just want a kick start on a) how I connect via a .NET app and b) how I can then start to pull out useful information such as current mailbox sizes, limits, mailbox rules etc etc

Thanks for reading, any thing you need me to clarify please ask

Answer (score 0):

> a) how I connect via a .NET app

We can use [the simple code](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started)  to connect the graph API

> b) how I can then start to pullout useful information such as current mailbox sizes, limits, mailbox rules etc etc

When we get the Accesstoken ,we can use the `/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings` to get the mailbox setting. For more detail about this endpoint, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings)

Comment: Thanks for replying - I can't see at the link you have given any "simple" code to connect to Graph API - as it seems to mention various languages but not VB or C# for a standard console or winforms app - hence my question - thanks

Comment: If you choose a language on [the site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/), there will be a section `Find code samples`

Comment: Yes I can see that - but as per my reply - none of the language options are C# or VB - hence the question and response.......... so no point me clicking on one as any code samples are not going to be in C# or VB which is the whole reason I posted in first place, had it been that easy I wouldn't have needed to ask...

Comment: There is a [console c# snippets sample code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-snippets-sample).

Comment: Thanks - hadn't seen that sample.  That at least allows me to connect to my Office 365 and it pulls out various information as a test.  But don't see how to get it to find mailbox size though

Comment: /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings doesn't seem to have mailbox size according to document you pointed me too -  it contains things such as language, archive settings, time zone, working hours